# AppleScript Quick Action Services Shortcut issue - MacOS Catalina

Tags: applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-catalina, automator, system-services

Running on: MacOS Catalina 10.15.5

I made a Quick Action in Automator and it works just fine. In fact, I've been using it for a few years. The code in the action itself is not the problem, nor is it allowing accessibility/controls in system preferences. My problem is mind-boggling to say the least and I cannot seem to figure it out and thought I'd ask the hive mind.

After making my quick action with AppleScript and making sure the 'workflow receives: no input in any application' as I normal would do, then going in and assigning the shortcut the key 'F13' in System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> Services, everything seems just great.

In the application I use this shortcut in, if I hover over the application main dropdown and hover over "Services" the item is there and has a shortcut 'F13' associated with it. If I select the shortcut from the dropdown menu, it works PERFECTLY.

Here is the problem, if I hit 'F13' on my keyboard, the service runs 3 times in a row. It's almost as if the system services thinks I want to run that particular item 3x. I have tried a number of different shortcut keys as well (as simple as: F13 and as complicated as: ⌘⌥⌃⇧N) and the shortcut keys did not yield any positive results either.

I have checked everywhere and cannot seem to find why this is happening. Any insight/help would be much appreciated. This is not an AppleScripting issue. It's something with the OS that is causing a triple selection on the services menu item for some reason. It does not seem to be a Key Repeater issue either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think, this is more about app usage (the automator) and not coding. you should consider the super user website. may be not here.

Comment: What does the Quick Action *DO*?

Comment: Thanks Jay and Ted for your responses. Jay, can you shoot me a link to the site you are referring?

Comment: Ted, the quick action is very simple really, it clicks a button on a window inside of an application that sends data to another application. Having the quick action is VERY helpful. When I press the shortcut key to run the quick action, the application window in the menu bar lights up three times indicating that I pressed the shortcut keys three times, then the service runs three times in a row and it screws itself up. It could be an Automator issue?

Comment: it's useful to add '@' tags to comments, so other people get notifications: e.g., type @Jay, and Jay will see that you have responded to him. The original question-asker will be notified of everything, and you can add a tag for one other person per comment.

Comment: To the point, this is odd behavior.  I assume you're using GUI scripting through system events to do the button pushing, but I can't see why it would fire three times (you might get weird behavior if the application you're trying to target is not in the foreground). Can you tell me (at least) what application you're trying to click a button in?

Comment: @TedWrigley Thanks for the insight and for your help. Sorry... newb on here. The application I am attempting to target is Avid Pro Tools. The script works just fine when I run it inside Automator, and it also runs perfectly when I select it from the services menu when the application is in the foreground as well as the background. The issue only happens when I try to use the shortcut key (which is the whole point of the script I wrote haha). It worked fine on High Sierra and Mojave, but for some reason on Catalina it is not yielding a good outcome.

Comment: @Jay tagging you for the notification.... sorry didn't know that was the way to communicate on here. :)

Comment: @postsoundmixer dont worry about it. super user is one site that i would recommend. and, I also see ted, helping you.

Comment: Well, I think I've discovered the problem. Running services by keyboard shortcut seems to invoke an automator service — com.automator.runner.xpc — in an alternate context that doesn't have proper security clearance. The three flashes you're seeing aren't the QA being invoked three times; they seem to be three separate error message invocations (one from the system, and two from whatever app is foremost when the shortcut is used). There's no obvious way to grant permission to this xpc. I'm thinking about other options

Comment: @TedWrigley That is VERY interesting. Come to think of it.. I may have had an com.automator.runner.xpc error pop up once. But you're right.... every other time it's just been the blinking as though there is an error. I thought it was a permissions thing too so I granted Automator Full Disk Access and it still did the same thing. Thank you for your insight. I'd love to hear any other possibilities you might think I can try in order to hopefully grant it access to run normally again.

Comment: @TedWrigley Thought I would follow up on this. Thanks!

Comment: I have a possible solution; I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @TedWrigley Thanks for the help. I will see what I can do to try and do this workaround soon. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as best as I can tell, isn't that the workflow is running three times, but that you're getting a series of three security error messages. It seems that when you try to run a service using a keyboard shortcut, the system invokes an xpc service (com.automator.runner.xpc, which is located inside the automator application package), and that service is triggering security alerts because it doesn't have the accessibility rights that are needed for GUI scripting. There is no obvious way to grant the xpc the proper rights (and I suspect that would be an enormous security hole anyway), so that's not workable.

However, there's a workaround. Take your functioning script, copy it into a new Script Editor window, and save it as an application using the 'File Format' pulldown at the lower left of the save window:

[image]

Give this application permission to use accessibility features:

- System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy → Accessibility

Now create a service in automator that uses the `Launch Application` action to launch the script application you just created. Assign your keyboard shortcut to that service, and things should work as you like.

Of course, this launches an application, showing it in the Dock and grabbing the foreground momentarily, which can be visually distracting. If you want it to run silently in the background, do the following:

1. Right-click on the icon for the script app and choose `Show Package Contents`.
2. Drill down two levels to find the `info.plist` file, and open it in TextEdit, BBEdit or some other plain-text editor
3. Add the following key/value pair to the file (being carful not to break up other key/value groups):

   ```
   <key>LSUIElement</key>
   <true/>
   ```
4. Save the info.plist file, then run the app again; it should be faceless.

Comment: IMO It's much easier to use **Terminal** and, e.g., `defaults write '/path/to/$name.app/Contents/Info.plist' LSUIElement -bool yes` replacing `/path/to/$name` as appropriate.

Comment: @user3439894: hah, that never would have occurred to me.